# When I run npm install in laravel 5.5 it show error in the middle of Installation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I run npm install in laravel 5.5 it show error at the middle of installation.I reinstall node.js and 
install new laravel but didn't work so if any one know please help me

here is the screen shot:
[image]

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.7.2 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.7.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\naqib\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-12T00_58_19_398Z-debug.log
```

can some one please help me with this

Comment: > 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Seems to me like you either didn't install node correctly or it just isn't available globally. If you just run `node -v` in console, what do you get?

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed node? Please install it first from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Comment: thanks for replay but the node is install correctly .actually i install it using yarn it works

Answer (score 0):

When I run into problems with NPM packages, my first debug step is to delete the `node_modules` folder, then reinstall all the packages (use command `yarn` or `npm install`). Have you given that a shot?